# Apache Camel-Oling2 read endpoint is not working

Tags: apache-camel, odata, olingo

I am using Apache Camel and trying to read Odata using Camel-Olingo2 component but i got "serviceUri" error everytime. I've tried documentation implementation but couldn't find any success. Please do let me know the way of connectivity with odata using camel-olingo2 component.

**Code:**

```
<bean id="parambean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
  <property name="sourceMap">
   <map  key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
     <entry key="serviceUri" value="http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc"/>
   </map>
  </property> 
 </bean> 

 <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
         <from uri="olingo2://read/Persons?queryParams=#parambean" />
         <to uri="file:D:\Camel\Output" />  
    </route> 
</camelContext>
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[olingo2://read/services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Persons‌​] <<< in
>   route: Route(route1)[[From[direct:...]] -> [To[olingo2://read/http:...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   olingo2://read/services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Persons due to:
>   serviceUri at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefini‌​tion.java:1072)

Comment: Can you add some code and uris you are using? Also, the exceptions you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a serviceUri to the end of your olingo component endpoint like below:

```
<from uri="olingo2://read/Persons?serviceUri=http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc" />
     <to uri="file:D:\Ca...
```

Is there a reason you wanted to create a map and use the reference of that for the component's properties rather than just adding it to the end of the endpoint?